# Remount / in docker or change mount options

Tags: mount, docker

Is there a way to control the way a container's root fs is mounted? Mine is using devicemapper + xfs on CentOS 7 and I need to pass it the "inode32" flag. "mount -o remount" doesn't work (no permission).

I have downloaded the docker source from github and tried to track down everything I can find, but "inode64" (the flag shown by the `mount` command) is only in a single test script.

Background: I have an old ARM compiler that is a 32-bit app, and even though it is calling `stat64` according to `ptrace`, it still overflows on the inode.